# magento extension dosent create navigation tab

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, magento-connect, magento-connect-manager

i have magento 1.9.3.8 and i had installed 2 extensions using magento MCM keys.
as you can see in screenshot , the extensions is installed into area #1 System > configuration area but not added to the navigation area #2 (where i can use it)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed user guide.

For 1 extension it is for featured product and there is not any menu for that they have added one attribute for products. You can select the product is featured product or not from product edit/new page. you can learn more about it from [here](https://magehit.com/magento-featured-products-extension.html#extension_userguide).

For 2 extension it is for product slider and there is not any menu for that. They have provided the only system configuration. you can learn more from [here](https://marketplace.magento.com/bigdrop-bigdrop-productslider.html).